# Como truncar decimal em X casas decimais?

Tags: c#, .net, arredondamento

Estou utilizando o seguinte código, porém quando envio ex:'10.100' para 2 casas ele retorna '10.1', mas deveria ser '10.10'

```
    public decimal TruncarDecimal(decimal value, int decimalPlaces)
    {
        decimal integralValue = Math.Truncate(value);

        decimal fraction = value - integralValue;

        decimal factor = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces);

        decimal truncatedFraction = Math.Truncate(fraction * factor) / factor;

        decimal result = integralValue + truncatedFraction;

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Dá suporte sim, [veja a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads). Ali tem sem o parâmetro de casas decimais, com esta informação e até como deve ser o critério do arredondamento.

```
Math.Round(valorDecimal, 2);
```

Se o que deseja não é arredondamento então faça o [`Truncate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Math_Truncate_System_Decimal_) escalando:

```
Math.Truncate(100 * valorDecimal) / 100;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/Truncate.cs).

Mas isto é basicamente o que está na pergunta.

Comment: Mas não posso arredondar, o Round altera o valor

Comment: Eu respondi o que estava na pergunta, agora você diz que não pode fazer o que pediu para fazer. Acho que a pergunta não está clara então.

Comment: eu citei o exemplo do Round que posso escolher as casas decimais, mas precisaria ser o truncate, so que eu pudesse escolher as casas, Quando utilizo o Math.Truncate(decimal), o parâmetro é apenas o valor.

Comment: O `Truncate()` também altera o valor, você precisa decidir se quer alterar o valor ou não. Por outro lado se é o `Truncate()` que quer usar, use ele, não sei o objetivo da pergunta nesta caso.

Comment: Vou tentar resumir pra você entender, eu faço multiplicações e os resultados dão ex: 1,64857, preciso retornar o valor com X casas decimais dependendo de cada caso, não vou mais dizer sobre truncate ou math, estou precisando fazer isto.

Comment: Se você não deixar claro o que quer não tem como responder do jeito que quer. Eu já coclqoeui duas possibilidades, se nenhuma das duas resolve, eu acho que e você não consegue dizer o que está errado com estas soluções. o problema é que você não sabe o que você quer fazer. Aí não tem como dar uma resposta, quando não se sabe qual é a pergunta. O que você perguntou foi respondido, se queria perguntar outra coisa, precisaria deixar claro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65850/discussion-between-bruno-rodrigues-and-bigown).

Answer (score 0):

Experimente usar o

```
Math.Truncate
```

por exemplo:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal a = 1.223M;
        double b = 2.913;

        a = Math.Truncate(a);
        b = Math.Truncate(b);

        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

Saídas:

```
1
2
```

Agora se você precisa exibir o valor com duas casas decimais use o código:

```
decimalVar.ToString("#.##");
```

Mais informações sobre *Math.Truncate* veja esse link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/fbf78553-93ab-4a96-9e1b-39160df5d216/truncar-variavel-para-apenas-2-decimais?forum=vscsharppt

Comment: Se puder adicione um link com a referência de alguma documentação que explique o que é o `Math.Truncate`.

Comment: Adicionado o link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/fbf78553-93ab-4a96-9e1b-39160df5d216/truncar-variavel-para-apenas-2-decimais?forum=vscsharppt

Comment: Eu preciso exibir exatamente com casas específicas, o truncate não deixa eu escolher o número de casas. E eu estou tentando fazer de forma genérica em um método que passo parâmetro de valor e número de casas decimais.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues você precisa arredondar pra cima ou para baixo? Se sim, onde trabalhava a gente usava a soma de + 0.4 no valor, assim ele aumentava pra cima, se usar -0.4 ele diminui pra baixo... aí trunca de forma natural, não sei se é seu caso, mas experimenta testar