# Como Truncar os valores decimais em C#

Tags: c#, .net

Estou tentando truncar os valores (sem arredondar) de acordo com a quantidade de casas decimais passadas por parâmetro, mas a função Math.Truncate não possui esse recurso... Existe alguma maneira de eu fazer isso?

```
public static decimal TruncarValor(decimal valor, int casasDecimais)
{
   return Math.Truncate(valor, casasDecimais????????);
}
```

Abraço a todos!

Comment: Master, isto te ajudaria? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238660/como-truncar-decimal-em-x-casas-decimais

Comment: Ajuda sim!!! Obrigado!! Comente no post principal que eu definirei como resposta :)